Expression cannot begin with
What is the problem with the following syntax:
(5^^ # &) /@ {2, 3}

The following error message is produced:
Syntax::sntxb: Expression cannot begin with "5^^#&".

Simpler forms have no problem, e.g.:
(5 # &) /@ {2, 3}

Thanx.

Based on the comment from @xzczd, as well as the other links referred to there, this is the complete answer to my question, which may be helpful to others:
5^FromDigits[ToString[#]] & /@ {2, 3}

Thank you.
